# Z-Score Plot of multiple series as one plot/histogram

Tags: r, netlogo

I am trying to make Zscores graph as given below.

[image: graph]
My data is based on NetLogo experiments and have repeated columns of same variables(say 10 times). It consists of different scenarios. I am trying to make a one representative graph to understand data. I am trying bit by bit. For the data given below lets say for Adaption scenario;

```
df <- data.frame(Biomass = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                 Livestock = c(2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20),
                 Totalpeople = c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100)
)
```

I suppose that Zscore will be a series we get from the data. How above type of graph can be made?
I am using these code;

```
df %>%  (.funs = function(x) {(x - mean(x)) / sd(x)}) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Scenario, y= value, fill = name)) + 
  geom_col(colour = 'black', position = position_dodge()) +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_fill_viridis_d() + ylab("Z-scores")
```

and gives error
Error in is.data.frame(x) :
'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
Please help!

Comment: Where is `Scenario`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for such a solution? Just created own `Scenario` like Limey did.

```
df %>%  
  as_tibble() %>% 
  add_column(Scenario_TarJae = as.factor(c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C"))) %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = c(1:3),
    names_to = "group",
    values_to = "value"
  ) %>% 
  group_by(Scenario_TarJae) %>% 
  mutate(z_score = scale(value)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Scenario_TarJae, y= z_score[,1], fill = group)) + 
  geom_col(colour = 'black', position = position_dodge()) +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_fill_viridis_d() + ylab("Z-scores")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank @Tarjae for great help.  Usually in excel we get multiple values of Z score for all variables. How these are cumulated to have a single value? What is the logic behind. How data frame of this graph will look like? can you please guide?

Answer (score 1):

You've not given us values for `Scenario` in you MWE, so it's not clear if you want to standardise *within* or *between* scenarios.  This code standardises within scenario: that is, it calculates the effect size for each column.

As always, it helps to tidy your data before you start: that is the effect of the call to `pivot_longer`.  Obviously, when you have your own `Scenario`, you can remove the `add_column` call.

```
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything(), values_to="value") %>% 
  add_column(Scenario="ADAPTATION") %>% 
  group_by(Scenario, name) %>% 
  summarise(value=(value - mean(value)/sd(value)), .groups="drop") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Scenario, y= value, fill = name)) +
    geom_col(colour = 'black', position = position_dodge()) +
    theme_classic() +
    scale_fill_viridis_d() + ylab("Z-scores")
```

[image]

Comment: thanks Limey. It is solving the problem. But I see the Zscore from my calculations lies between -2 and +3 for variables in DF.  I am confused that how these are being calculated?

Comment: It's imposible to explain the difference as you haven't shown us your data.

Comment: I am taking about the 'sample' data frame I have shared in my question. Zscores in sample data is between -2  and +3.